# Native iOS app: What do I put in Facebook's developer "iPhone App Store ID" under Settings, Basic?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm about finished with a native iPhone app, but I need to finish SSO via Facebook. Despite my best effort, I am unable to figure-out what value is supposed to go in the "iPhone App Store ID" field during the process where I register my app with Facebook on their website.

I have an "App ID" at http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/bundles/, but Facebook gives me the error "iPhone App Store ID must be an integer" when I put my App ID in that field. My App ID is not an integer.

I know Facebook specifically labels the field with "App Store"; please tell me that isn't really the case, since... how would anyone have something on the "App Store" if it's still in development?

Everyone has "that issue" that motivates their first Stack Overflow post, and this is mine. I eagerly await news that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Create a new app in iTunes Connect. That app will have a unique app id. *That's* the id they want. That is, in fact, the App Store id for the app.

Comment: @Greg: You can create the app in iTunes Connect (and get the id) without actually submitting your binary.

Comment: Thanks, all. That's the level of support I expected from SO members. Much appreciated.

Comment: However, unless it is actually in the stores, you will get "Your iPhone App Store ID is invalid because the iTunes App Store reports your app as being unavailable for iPhone and iPod Touch".

Comment: i have the same problem i have created app in itunesconnect but when i enters my app id in iphone storeid in facebook developers app portal it shows me wrong please suggest me what to do ?

Comment: There is an "iPhone Store ID" and a "iPad Store ID". I have only one "App Store id". Shall I fill both "Store ID" with the same "App Store id".

Comment: I think so, yes. The IDs are one and the same for both iPad and iPhone, if your app is universal.

Comment: The ID is of an unpublished app will not work. Facebook will tell you that it is not able to retrieve the iphone/ipad store id from apple.

Comment: Using 0 does not work anymore. I user empty space " " for iPhone Store ID and iPad Store ID and new platform was added. As mentioned multiple times - do not forget to update these two fields when publishing app

Answer (score 51):

The accepted answer is true, but the [iOS SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/) docs also say

> iPhone App Store ID - If you have an iPhone app that is listed in the
>   iTunes App Store enter the ID here, e.g. 123456. If Facebook links out
>   to your app and finds that the user does not have your app installed,
>   then it will take the user to your app in the store. The user can then
>   install your app. If your app is not in the iTunes App Store you can
>   **enter any valid app's ID** but be sure to update this when your app is
>   approved in the App Store.

Emphasis mine.

This is what I did. I use an existing public app ID (picked one at random from the store) because my app isn't out yet..

Comment: Question: how can I update the ID after Apple approves my app? I must make a new build, upload it, and wait again to be approved, isn't it?

Comment: @SavaMazăre I haven't gone through this process in about a year. But when I did last year, I was able to change the Facebook app's "iPhone App Store ID" before the facebook app went live.

Answer (score 22):

Right now, the simplest solution is to just type in "0" as iPhone App Store ID - a solution which is also demonstrated in the Facebook SDK Getting Started Guide: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/

Comment: Yeah but when I save changes using 0, it just disappears.. making me wonder if it did anything at all.

Comment: You can leave it empty, but 0 results in an error message at this point.

Answer (score 17):

For already published apps, it is part of itunes url appearing at the end
https://itunes.apple.com/.../idxyzabc123
xyzabc123 is the id for above url

Answer (score 16):

For testing use **0(Zero)**,

- iPhone Store ID = 0
- iPad Store ID   = 0

and click on **Save Changes**.

**0** Will be disappeared but your work will be done.

Note:- update this id before going live.

Comment: I am facing issue described over here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097346/itunes-store-operation-failed-the-app-references-non-public-selectors-in-payload is it somehow related to your answer ?

Comment: I don't think that @AshishKarpe

Comment: do you have any idea on my issue, I am badly stuck please help me out !

Answer (score 9):

If you're app is already published, open your app on iTunes Connect → General → App Information → Apple ID. You need to copy this number into the iPhone Store ID in Facebook Developers dashboard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, you can use "0" for development.

If you login to iTunes Connect and visit your app, it should be under "Apple Id".

Comment: While it may have worked before, the Facebook app console today rejects 0 as a value!

Comment: Use empty " " space instead