# What is the difference between Facebook iOS settings "iPhone Store Id" and "iPad Store Id"

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad, mobile

I understand what the Apple Id is for my iOS app (obtained from the iTunes Connect listing). However, when setting up a Facebook app to accept install pings from an iOS app, it asks for *two* ids:

- **iPhone Store Id** with hint text of "The ID to identify your app in the iOS Store"
- **iPad Store Id** with hint text of "The ID to identify your app in the iPad Store"

As explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7746037/249239), the iPhone Store Id should use the app's Apple Id.

But what is the iPad Store Id? Should it be left blank or should it use the same id?

Note: My understanding of bundle ids is that they map to a unique app id. So presumably the same bundle id cannot be used for two separate apps, one for iPhones and one for iPads.

Clarification much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iPhone and iPad store ID are both the iOS store identifier. But they are separate because not every builds universal apps.

This is because your iPad app could have a different store id then your iPhone app.

Facebook allows you to enter more then one Bundle ID if needed, which will be the case if you have a separate app for the iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I see what you mean. I didn't notice that iOS setup on Facebook allowed for multiple bundle IDs -- I assumed it was just a single package (bundle ID) as with Android. What confuses me (still) is why it is possible to specify a seemingly arbitrary number of bundle IDs when what is needed (presumably) is the bundle ID for the iPhone version and its corresponding app id and the similar data for the iPad version.

Comment: Maybe your internal test version has a different bundle ID, it is the case from some of my project. Then it is great you have more then one bundle ID.