# What do I put in Facebook's developer "iPhone App Store ID" if my app is not published yet?

Tags: facebook

This answer ([Native iOS app: What do I put in Facebook's developer "iPhone App Store ID" under Settings, Basic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746019/native-ios-app-what-do-i-put-in-facebooks-developer-iphone-app-store-id-unde)) has good info **if** your app is published. But what if your app is not published yet?

I want to test the ability to log in to FB **before** I publish the app to the store, so what should I put as the iPhone Store ID?